# React Hook "useEffect" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

```
export const FetchDailyData = () => {
  try {

    const [data, setData] = useState({ numbers: [], isFetching: false });

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            setData({ ...data, isFetching: true });
            const response = await axios.get(`${apiURL}/daily`);
            setData({
                ...data,
                numbers: response.data.slice(0, 50),
                isFetching: false
            });
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [data]); 

    console.log(`data= ${data.numbers} isFetching= ${data.isFetching}`);

  } catch (error) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(error);
    setData({ ...data, isFetching: false });
  }
}
```

Please can anyone help me fix this issue? I tried to fetch api data but this error I cannot handle.

Comment: Why do you surround the entire function body in a try/catch? Should just wrap the minimal code that throws errors. Also, what is `FetchDailyData`? It's not a functional component, is it meant to be a custom react hook? Can you update question to include the caller's code (i.e. where and how `FetchDailyData` is used)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to place useEffect inside a if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66024000/is-it-possible-to-place-useeffect-inside-a-if-statement)

Answer (score 3):

You can't wrap `useEffect` in anything that might cause it not to run, including try/catch.  Looking at what you are doing, this is probably a better option:

```
export const FetchDailyData = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({ numbers: [] });
    const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await axios.get(`${apiURL}/daily`);
            setData({
                ...data,
                numbers: response.data.slice(0, 50),
            });
        }
        try {
            setFetching(true);
            fetchData();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        } finally {
            setFetching(false);
        }
    }, [data]); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your `useEffect` call is inside a `try/catch`, it’s possible for the effect to not run on a given render. It’s predicated on whether something throws. Hooks must run in the same order in each render—I *think* it has to do with how React tracks them internally—and the `try/catch` makes it possible for that call to get skipped.

If you’re just worried about the fetch throwing, move the try/catch inside the hook instead of the other way around.